# PHP Excel library sheet naming and order

Tags: php, phpexcel

So I Am using `PHPExcel` library in order to create dynamic reports from my `PSQL` database.

I Will first show what I am doing:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Koordynator")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("SystemTest")
                             ->setTitle("GeneratedTest")
                             ->setKeywords("Test")
                             ->setCategory("TestCategory");

$db = ConnectionFactory::CreateConnection();
$systemArray= array (
                    "systems which are processed"=>"system",
                    "Persons responsible for systems"=>"person",
                    "Software used inside of implementation"=>"software",
                    "Hardware used inside of solution"=>"hardware");

$system= array ("id"=>"system_id","System name"=>"name","System price"=>"price");
$person= array("Firstname of admin"=>"firstname","Lastname of admin"=>"lastname");
$software=array("Software id"=>"id, "System Name"=>"name", "System License"=>"license");
$hardware=array("id"=>"id","Graphic"=>"gpu","Procesor"=>"cpu","Memory"=>"ram");
```

In this place I will describe what those arrays are for. First one `$systemArray` contains list of tables in my database where `"key"=>"value"` stands for `key`- name of sheet and A1 cell, `value` is table name.

arrays `$system, $person $software and $hardware` are arrays which contains definition of column in each array where `"key"=>"value"` stands for `key`- name of column in sheet, `value` name of column in table.

and this is how i create the `XLS`

```
foreach ($systemArray as $tableKey=>$tableName) {
    //$q = "select * from $tableName where date >= '2013-11-01' and date <= '2013-11-30' order by date asc;";
    $i=0;
    foreach($$tableName as $key=>$value){
        if ($i==0)
            $selectValue = $value ;
        else
            $selectValue = $selectValue." , ".$value ;
        $i++;
    }

    $q= "select $selectValue, date from $tableName where date >= '2013-11-01' and date <= '2013-11-30' order by date asc";
    $i=3;
    $s=0;
    $aa=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $tableKey);
    //echo "klucz: $tableKey <br> a teraz $aa<br>";
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet($s);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(substr($aa,0,30));

    $letters = range('A','Z');
    foreach ($db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
            $k=1;
            //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('1');
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue('A1', $tableKey);
            foreach($$tableName as $columnkey=>$columnValue){
                if ($i == 3){
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue('A'.($i-1), 'Data');
                    if ( $k <25)
                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue($letters[$k].($i-1), $columnkey);
                    else 
                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue('A'.$letters[($k-25)].($i-1), $columnkey);
                }
                if ($k<25)
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue($letters[$k].$i, $row[$columnValue]);
                else
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue('A'.$letters[($k-25)].$i, $row[$columnValue]);
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($s)->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row['date']);
                //echo $letters[$k].$i." $columnName<br>";
                $k++;
            }
            //$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($k.$i, $row['date']);
            $i++;
    }
    $s++;
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

The problem I encountered is that somehow `sheets` in the `XLS` are being displayed in the wrong order and what I mean by that they are not in the order I put them in `$systemArray` the other thing is that they are named in a weird way. first one is named `Worksheet 1`, and the rest is ok but there is always `1` added at the end of the name like `systems which are processed 1`.

Can anyone point me where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: To start, you're creating each new sheet at the 0 position (`$objPHPExcel->createSheet($s);` where $s is 0), which means "at the beginning", shuffling all existing sheets "down" the line; so your sheets will all be ordered in the reverse order that they're being created. To order the sheets in the order that you create them, call `$objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL);` or simply `$objPHPExcel->createSheet();` which will create the new sheet at the end

Comment: Secondly, when you instantiate a new PHPExcel object, it automatically creates a single sheet for you called "Worksheet"

Comment: Thirdly, you may (though I can't be certain) have identified a bug in setTitle() for the worksheet that automatically adds an incrementing number to the end of the sheet name if it believes that another sheet with that name already exists - that I'll investigate further

Comment: @MarkBaker Your comments are very useful, I believe someone else could make use of it either ;) I would like to reward them with +1 and answer mark. Thx again!